# Tagging London Life

Tags: discussion, tags

Professor Layton and the Last Specter comes out in the US today, and with it comes the (apparently) 100 hour RPG bonus, London Life. It's likely to have its own set of questions, separate from the main game.

Should it share a tag with Last Specter? Or should it be tagged separately?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I think it should be tagged separately as, although the games are on the same cart, they are not actually the same game.

Comment: I Agree 110% /10char

Comment: That makes sense to me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I retagged your question as [prof-layton-london-life](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prof-layton-london-life) just to get the name of the main game in there somehow. It's not perfect, cause the full version runs over the tag length limit, but in the absence of other Professor Layton tags, it seems reasonable.

Comment: I think this is best.

Comment: Someone changed that back to just being "London Life" - so I am just going to leave it at that, I think.

Comment: @AshleyNunnThat was me. Community support is obviously in favour of the suggestion made by Powerlord, so that's the one we should go with.